# Outlook Add In VSTO

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto, preview

I'm still quite in the field of programming. But now I have come across small problem. I'm currently working on an Outlook add-in that takes an email and packs it into a new mail as an attachment and automatically sends it to a specific address. That works well so far. However, it only works if I have opened the mail that I want to send as an attachment in a new window.

My goal, however, would be that it is already sufficient if the mail is open in the reading area. However, I have unfortunately not found a way to address this area. Maybe someone can give me a link or an example to address the mail, which is currently displayed in the preview with Visual Studio. As a language I use C #.

So far I reach the opened mail as follows:

```
String path = "C:\\Test\\Mail.msg";

Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
MailItem mailitem = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem
```

But how do I reach the mail that can be seen as a preview in the reading area?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently selected item from the Explorer window in Outlook you need to use the following code:

```
        if (Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
        {
            Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message." +
                    " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ".";
                mailItem.Display(false);
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.ContactItem)
            {
                Outlook.ContactItem contactItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.ContactItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a contact." +
                    " The full name is " + contactItem.Subject + ".";
                contactItem.Display(false);
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.AppointmentItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is an appointment." +
                    " The subject is " + apptItem.Subject + ".";
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.TaskItem)
            {
                Outlook.TaskItem taskItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.TaskItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a task. The body is "
                    + taskItem.Body + ".";
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.MeetingItem)
            {
                Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.MeetingItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a meeting item. " +
                     "The subject is " + meetingItem.Subject + ".";
            }
        }
```

But if you need to get all selected items in the Explorer view you need to iterate over all items in the `Selection` object.

Comment: Wow thank you ver much. Not it works ;-) Realy thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection to loop through the selected messages and process them appropriately.

Keep in mind that (just like with `Application.ActiveInspector)`, you can have items other than `MailItem`, e.g. `ContactItem`, `AppointmentItem`, `ReportItem`, etc. You need to handle items like that.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I'll try it right away.

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!